# Flutter : Align radio in wrap widget in column

Tags: flutter, dart

I found [one duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65697530/radio-button-alignment-in-flutter) on this but that was not created dynamically as I do here which is using a `List` because I might want to add new items. So how do I align cause my 2nd column of radios arent vertically aligned.
[image: radio on the second column is not aligned]
Here's my code:

```js
List<OptionList> optList = [
    OptionList(name: "Super Fast", total: 20, index: 1, price: 50),
    OptionList(name: "Fast", total: 6, index: 2, price: 20),
    OptionList(name: "Regular", total: 5, index: 3, price: 10),
    OptionList(name: "Slow", total: 5, index: 3, price: 5),
  ];

Wrap(
    spacing: 20,
    runSpacing: 15,
    direction: Axis.horizontal,
    alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
    runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: optList.map((data) => Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                   children: [
                        Radio(
                           value: data.name,
                           groupValue: data.index,
                           onChanged: (val) {
                               setState(() {
                                   speed = data.name;
                                   id = data.index;
                               });
                           }),
                           Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                 Text("${data.total}" ' ' "${data.name}"),
                                 Text('~'"${data.price}" ' ')
                              ],
                           ),
                       ],)).toList(),
    ),
```

Comment: Image is not accessible, Can you directly include on Stack Overflow

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I've attached the image

Comment: I would suggest you use `GridView` here. It will place your widgets in proper alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap children are different sizes  and `alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,`, that why you are having this issue. You can provide fixed with that solves the issue but this also depend on text size. If you are fixed with these string 120 width is enough.

```dart
children: optList
    .map(
      (data) => SizedBox(
        width: 120,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Radio(
                value: data.name,
                groupValue: data.index,
                onChanged: (val) {}),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("${data.total}" ' ' "${data.name}"),
                Text('~' "${data.price}" ' ')
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
    .toList(),
```

If you have overflow with long text, you can wrap `Column` with `Expanded` widget.

Answer (score 1):

By using GridView, you can convert your code to something like this:

```
return GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    childAspectRatio: 4,
  ),
  itemCount: optList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Radio<dynamic>(
            value: data.name,
            groupValue: data.index,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                speed = data.name;
                id = data.index;
              });
            }),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: const [
            Text("${data.total}" ' ' "${data.name}"),
            Text('~' "${data.price}" ' ')
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```